# Read VSTS/TFS extension version from extension code

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, manifest.json, azure-devops-extensions

Is there any way to read extension version number from within the extension?

We are manually adding version to **vss-extension.json** and **task.json** . It will be great help if someone provide guidelines to retrieve version from either of these places.

1) vss-extension.json
[image]

2) task.json

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could  use  [Build and Release tasks for Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-developer-tools-build-tasks) which released  by Microsoft.

This extension provides build and release tasks for packaging and publishing Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) extensions to the Visual Studio Marketplace.

[image]
Use the **query version** task: query an extension's version (*to make it easy to increment on your next package or publish*)

For how to do this, you could refer the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-build-release-tasks/blob/master/BuildTasks/ExtensionVersion/ExtensionVersion.ts) in GitHub.